# Jersey receive multipart file and store it in temp folder

Tags: jakarta-ee, jax-rs, multipartform-data, jersey-2.0, file-handling

I'm trying to write a jersey REST api to upload files. After receiving the file I have to save the file in some temporary folder and send file to another server for processing. I'm stuck at the part where I save the file in a temp folder with the received file name. How to handle files uploaded from multiple clients with the name. Because files with same name gets replaced by the latest file. I don't want to rename the file. Is there a way handle this.

Below is my current implementation

```
@POST @Path("/uploadfile") @Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
public Response uploadFile(@FormDataParam("file") InputStream uploadedInputStream,
  @FormDataParam("file") FormDataContentDisposition fileDetails, @FormDataParam("meta") String requestMeta) {

String fileLocation = System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir") + "/"+ System.currentTimeMillis() + "/" + fileDetails.getFileName(); //rename file with timestamp which I need to find a another way so that I can persist my file name
File file = writeToFile(uploadedInputStream,
    fileLocation);
return Response.status(Response.Status.OK).entity(uploadAndGetDetails(file, requestMeta)).build();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could consider [`UUID`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/UUID.html).

It is not guaranteed to be unique but the probability of a duplicate is extremely low:

```
String uuid = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
```

Comment: I don't want to rename the file. Im looking for other ways without renaming.

Comment: @arjun You could create a directory with a unique name and store the file with the original name into the newly created directory.

Comment: @arjun It may be a bit hacky, but if your file system supports it, you could persist the _original_ file name as an [attribute of the file](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#setAttribute-java.nio.file.Path-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object-java.nio.file.LinkOption...-).